# hibernate criteria get records with max column value after joining 3 tables

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I am writing a web application with spring mvc and hibernate and I use hibernate criteria to do searching to give resultset with a max column value, but i have a problem that I do not know how to translate the following SQL statement into hibernate criteria code:

```
select * from
(select  md.display_id as mddisid, 
md.type as mdtype, 
ml.list_id, md.vo, 
md.status, 
md.dt_received, 
md.dt_ack,
md.dt_status, 
md.dt_appr,ml.dt_issue, 
ae.dt_enquiry, 
ae.dt_reply, 
ae.sys_app_id as sysappid, 
ae.type, 
ae.seq_no as sq
from md_app md
LEFT JOIN md_list ml
ON md.sys_app_id = ml.sys_app_id 
LEFT JOIN app_enq ae
ON ml.sys_app_id = ae.sys_app_id
where md.app_id = "AN000008") a
inner join (
select  md.display_id as mddisid, 
max(ae.seq_no) as maxsq
from md_app md
LEFT JOIN md_list ml
ON md.sys_app_id = ml.sys_app_id 
LEFT JOIN app_enq ae
ON ml.sys_app_id = ae.sys_app_id
where md.app_id = "AN000008" <-- an ID provided for searching
group by mddisid
) ss on a.mddisid = ss.mddisid and a.sq = ss.maxsq
```

the criteria  I have written for now:

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(MdApp.class, "mdapp");          
            cr.createAlias("mdapp.mdLists", "mdls", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN); 
            cr.createAlias("mdapp.appEnqs", "ae", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN); 
            cr.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.projectionList()
                 .add(Projections.property("mdapp.displayId").as("displayId"))
                 .add(Projections.property("mdapp.type").as("type"))
                 .add(Projections.property("mdls.listId").as("listId"))
                 .add(Projections.property("mdapp.dbUser").as("dbUser"))
                 .add(Projections.property("mdapp.status").as("status"))
                 .add(Projections.property("mdapp.dtReceived").as("dtReceived"))
                 .add(Projections.property("mdapp.dtAck").as("dtAck"))
                 .add(Projections.property("mdapp.dtStatus").as("dtStatus"))
                 .add(Projections.property("mdapp.dtAppr").as("dtAppr"))
                 .add(Projections.property("mdls.dtIssue").as("dtIssue"))
                 .add(Projections.property("ae.dtEnquiry").as("dtEnq"))
                 .add(Projections.property("ae.dtReply").as("dtReply"))
                 .add(Projections.property("ae.id.sysAppId").as("sysAppId"))
                 .add(Projections.property("ae.id.type").as("AppEnqtype"))
                 .add(Projections.property("ae.id.seqNo").as("seq"))    

                 ));
```

gives the resultset like this, less columns for easy illustration:

> ```
>   app_id   seq_number
>    AN01       1
>    AN01       2
>    AN03       1
>    AN03       2
>    AN03       3
>    AN04       1
> ```

but i want to achieve:

> ```
>   app_id   seq_number       
>    AN01       2       
>    AN03       3
>    AN04       1
> ```

I have tried detached criteria i googled online, but it seems for situation when one record is selected. I also tried using *groupProperty* of the *app_id* and *max* of *seq_number*, only records with seq_number = 1 are given.

As I have stuck on this for several days.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native query in hibernate using createSQLQuery.